# How to get 220 VAC from 2-phase 110 VAC

Tags: single-phase

I purchase Dental sintering Oven KDF Zircom Speed which have single phase 220 VAC. My problem is my wall plug have 2 phase 110 V AC. What can I do to have single phase 220 V AC?

Comment: "Two-phase" 120 VAC is split 220 VAC, single phase. All you should need is connection to a 220 VAC outlet, such as used by electric ranges and dryers.

Comment: Please add the power requirement to the question. (2.5 kVA?)

Comment: Where are you located?

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen.  The unit requires too much power to be able to power from a common 120V outlet.  Even with a step-up transformer, you will have circuit breaker trips at inopportune times, causing you to lose work and have to repeat patient procedures.

The unit costs over $10,000, so hiring a licensed electrician to run a dedicated circuit will cost less than the sales tax.

Answer (score 0):

> is my wall plug have 2 phase 110vac

You don't. You have 1-phase 110 Vac.

> What can I do to have single phase 220vac ?

You get an autotransformer. https://www.google.com/search?q=autotransformer+120%2F240v

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/power-supplies-transformers/transformers/autotransformers/